# Backbone Routers, URLs and Test/Production Web Contexts

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

In my Backbone application I have a main view that shows previews of posts. When the user clicks on a post, the post is expanded in an overlay and the URL is changed to reflect that post. While the post is expanded the user may do something that triggers a call to the server that needs to happen at the root context. The problem is that when the post is expanded, the server call that needs to happen at the root context happens from the post context instead. Here's the order of operations:

1. Page is loaded with main view url: **http://localhost:8080/my-web-app/**
2. User clicks post, overlay is shown, url updated to: **http://localhost:8080/my-web-app/posts/1**
3. User clicks something that triggers a call to server. Url is: **http://localhost:8080/my-web-app/posts/1/load**, which is wrong.

In the example above, the load operation needs to happen from the root context: **http://localhost:8080/my-web-app/load**

I've tried changing the url property for my models, collections, etc. to include a leading /, but this removes the "/my-web-app/" context (the url becomes **http://localhost:8080/load**), which is necessary in my test environment. This would work fine in a production environment, of course.

To get around this, I have set the Backbone.history root option to be "/my-web-app/" and have overridden every url property to be as follows:

```
url: function() {
  (Backbone.history.options.root != undefined ? Backbone.history.options.root : "") + "load";
}
```

While this approach works, it is a pain in the ass to override every url function like this... not to mention, it feels hacky. It is also totally unecessary code for a production environment. Is there a more elegant way to manage this so that it works in both test and production environments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application routing shouldn't differ on dev environment and production. This will always bring trouble at some point.

Assuming you're using Apache server on your localhost, you can make a virtual host of your choice and make `/my-web-app/` available on the `/`.

First, add a domain name to your /etc/hosts file and point it to 127.0.0.1, like that:

```
127.0.0.1   mywebapphost
```

and then add a virtual host to your Apache `vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/someone/Sites/my-web-app/" # absolute directory of your webapp
    ServerName mywebapphost
</VirtualHost>
```

And you're done! Your webapp is available on //mywebapphost:8080 and all routing is identical to your production environment.

Comment: I considered this... and it would certainly solve the problem. The reason I didn't do it is because it is theoretically possible for me to be testing two webapps using the same server. In that case, it wouldn't work. That said, I'm only testing one webapp right now so I'll give this a shot. Btw, I'm using tomcat... same concept applies though!

Comment: you can add another vhost for another webapp, so you can test multiple webapps on one server (but with different vhosts)

Comment: Right, but only one that can be at root ("/"). So theoretically, the javascript for all the other webapps would suffer the same problem with the context path. I did make the synonymous change to my tomcat config and everything is working great. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem and after stressing for a while realized that you can use the * as a prefix to your routes to eliminate the problem with the web context:

```
*posts/1/load
```

The only downside is that the route resolution needs to do more work but given that it's client side it should be negligible.

While it may be true that your routes shouldn't differ between dev, qa production, I think it's fair to say that a lot of web applications are written to be context agnostic so the client side stuff should follow suit imho.